# Crash in viewWillAppear of simple ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a pretty simple view controller listed at the end.

Currently it is crashing randomly (about 9 times in the last 24 hours with 20,000 Daily active users on this version) on this line `titleLabel.text = alertTitle`

What would cause this to happen, is it because of the weak reference on titleLabel?

```
class AlertViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cosmosStarRating: CosmosView!
@IBOutlet weak var alertLabel: UILabel!

var alertText = ""
var alertTitle = ""
var showStars = false

var appear: () -> () = {}
var disappear: () -> () = {}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    titleLabel.text = alertTitle
    alertLabel.text = alertText
    if (!showStars) {
        cosmosStarRating.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    appear()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    disappear()
}
}
```

Comment: You tell us. What does the crash report _say_?

Comment: My money is on unwired outlets. Anyone?

Comment: Nicolas, as I said, its only 9 crashes out of 20,000 uses. How would it be unwired 9 times.....

Answer (score 1):

You should start by including your symbolicated crash report.

But try this:

In your `AppDelegate` file, remove (or comment out) the line at the top that says:

```
@UIApplicationMain
```

Then add a `main.swift` file to your project with the following code:

```
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv).bindMemory(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self, capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)), nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)) // Rename AppDelegate.self as required
```

I know this may sound crazy, but it just solved a crash exactly like yours that I was fighting for a couple of weeks. I was getting hundreds of crash reports, across tonnes of different builds (beta testers using TestFlight), and they all pointed to the same ViewController file, and the same line. It didn't matter what that line was doing. I reordered commands to change things up, I even at one point commented out the entire class! Same crash reports, same file, same line.

I swapped over to using a `main.swift` file as above instead of the auto generated one, and voila, crash reports started making sense, pointing to the `UIApplicationMain()` line because the crash was happening in one of Apple's frameworks (it was my bug, but the crash didn't appear in my code, it went up to Apple's before it triggered the crash). But I was able to figure that out only after switching to the `main.swift` code. I guess there's some bug in the symbolication that happens when using the `@UIApplicationMain` method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `viewcontroller` `titleLabel` instance is initializing after `ViewWillappear` method gets invoked. And you are trying to access inside `ViewWillappear` method and also it is forced unwrapped if it is nil then if try to access it will crash. You can try like this either declare your outlet optional

> `@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel?`

or move your code inside ViewDidAppear method to prevent the crash.